# Using DateTime object as DataMember?

Tags: wcf

I need to send in my web service some information about the time + date .
So i want to use the DateTime.

Can i define the DateTime  as DataMember ? 
I try to define it as as datamember - but i got an exception ( catastrophic failure )

Comment: I can only say 'well done!'. I've been programmming with .NET for a while and don't see the exception 'catastrophic failure' very often!

Comment: It can be for other reason this exception not only because the dateTime.

Comment: yes. It should be possible to use datetime as a web service return value, or parameter.

Comment: Can you **show us** some code?!?!? Your service method, the data contract you're using - and the **exact and complete** exception message(s) you're getting.... otherwise, this is a guessing game - at best!

Comment: I was always wondering if framework creators would ever show us some code?!?!?!? It's clear that int and string work out of the box, but aside from these, collections and date values are quite basic but no example can be found for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Create new WCFDate class, and this class outputs a string in a set format, this allows it to be easily read by what ever needs to. Then replace all of Ur DateTimes with WCFDate.

```
public class WCFDate
{
public static string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zz";

public string Data { get; set; }

public WCFDate() { }

public WCFDate(string data)
{
    Data = data;
}

public WCFDate(DateTime date)
{
    Data = date.ToString(DateTimeFormat);
}

public WCFDate(DateTime? date)
{
    if (date.HasValue)
    {
        Data = date.Value.ToString(DateTimeFormat);
    }
}

public bool HasDate
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Data);
    }
}

public DateTime GetDate()
{
    try
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(Data, DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch
    {
        return new DateTime();
    }
}
```